# VPN - 3 Domains Active Directory - Sync DNS

Tags: vpn, domain-name-system, active-directory, microsoft

I have 3 AD domains on 3 remote sites. I configure a VPN Site2Site and it works great.

I would like to resolve all my hostnames by using my DNS servers.

I have 3 independent DCs and 3 DNS servers. What's the best option to configure my 3 DNS servers to talk together? I don't want to create an AD forest or any link between the different DCs.

Comment: This is not an information security question, but you'd likely get an answer on Server Fault. Voting for migrating this question there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stub forward lookup zone on each domain that points to the name server of the other domains' DNS server.

[image: Stub Zone]